# Amazon checkout payment button integration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

i am integrated amazon checkout payment button code is given below.

```
<form action="https://authorize.payments-sandbox.amazon.com/pba/paypipeline" method="post">
```

`<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="http://abcd.com/abcd.php" >`

```
<input type="hidden" name="processImmediate" value="1" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="signatureMethod" value="" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="accessKey" value="" >  
  <input type="hidden" name="collectShippingAddress" value="0" >  
  <input type="hidden" name="isDonationWidget" value="0" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="amazonPaymentsAccountId" value="" >    
  <input type="hidden" name="cobrandingStyle" value="logo" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="immediateReturn" value="1" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="USD 10" >   
  <input type="hidden" name="description" value="product payment" >  
  <input type="hidden" name="abandonUrl" value="http://abcd.com/abcd.php" >
  <input type="hidden" name="signatureVersion" value="2" >
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="" >   
  <input type="image" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/asp/beige_small_paynow_withmsg_whitebg.gif" border="0">   
</form>
```

in that button form amount is `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="USD 10" >` and when i am changing this to some other values getting error like

Invalid Request
Error Message:
Input parameter signature is invalid

how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

Hi Friend you can not change any value directly because it effect on its signature value and if signature is not match on amazon server they will give you above error so you can calculate signature after any changes.